# React remove item from array by using filter function, why does the uuid keeps changing?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, components, uuid

I'm making a To Do List app using React, I made 2 components which is the App component and the ToDoItem component, In the App component I have 2 states one of them is being used to add tasks and the second is to set the items array, In the ToDoItem component I have a state that is being used to mark items (Setting its text decoration to line through).
I'm also using UUID to make a uniqe key to each one of the components,
The problem is that everytime I try to remove an item from the list, it doesn't working and its also changes the uuids

App component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ToDoItem from "./ToDoItem";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


  function handleChange(event){
    const newItem = event.target.value;
    setItem(newItem);
  }

  function addItem(){
    if(item.length > 0){
      console.log(item + " inserted!");
      setItems( (prevItems) =>{
        return[...prevItems, item];
      });

      setItem("");
    }
  }

  function deleteItem(id){
    setItems((prevItems) =>{
      return prevItems.filter(
        (key) => {
          return key !== id;
        }
      )
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={item}/>
        <button onClick={addItem}>
          <span>Add</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
         { items.map((todoItem) => ( 
         <ToDoItem 
         key={uuidv4()} 
         id={uuidv4()} //Must be used in order to be able to use it or deleting an item
         item={todoItem}
         onDelete={deleteItem}
         />
         ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ToDoItem component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { BiTrash } from "react-icons/bi";

function ToDoItem(props){
    const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    function markItem(){
        setChecked(prevValue => {
                return !prevValue;
        });
    }


    return(
    <li ><span onClick={markItem} style={{textDecoration: isChecked ? "line-through" : "none"}}>
        {props.item}</span> {isChecked ? 
        <span className="trash" onClick={() => {
            props.onDelete(props.id);
            }}>
        <BiTrash/></span> : null}</li>
    );
}

export default ToDoItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

On every `App` render you make a  function call (uuid()) which results in new keys (unmount) and new id, you should move the id prop to your `todoItem` state on creation:

```
// on creating a todo item
const todoItem = { id: uuid() }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought was happening, I didn't know how to solve this, I still did not quite understand, So to clear things up I need to make a state for the ID? and than add it at the li creation? ```<li key={todoItem}>```

Comment: Yes, key={todoItem.id} id={todoItem.id}

Comment: I'm getting an error that the component has not key (removed from the App component the key and the id)

Comment: Why remove they key prop? Just dont generate it. Either way you should just upload your example into codesandbox see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-khayyam-pnp49

Comment: You sandbox is empty

Comment: Sorry, my bad https://codesandbox.io/s/to-do-list-app-pnp49